# Iterating over unsat cores

Tags: constraints, z3, smt

I use `(get-unsat-core)` in `Z3` to extract an unsat-core of an unsatisfiable set of constraints. However, some constraints may have more than one unsat core. In such cases,  is there any way to iterate over unsat-cores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it isn't totally straight-forward. The MARCO algorithm by Mark Liffiton and collaborators and variants are good bets for extracting multiple cores. 
The Z3 distribution comes with a Python example of a simplified MARCO algorithm.
There are other variants described on http://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/mod.html#/sec-cores-correction-sets-satisfying-assignments